# webform date popup format

Tags: webforms, datetime

I have a webform with a popop date the problem is the date in the textbox is shown in the format

```
2014-7-30
```

it need it to be

30/7/2014

how can I change this?

Answer (score -1):

I use webform 7.x-3.20 it doesn't give text box option for date field rather it show select list except for year. If in your case it showing textbox make sure the configuration is as followed.

You can create new date format under date and time settings, Go to `admin/config/regional/date-time/formats`

Add new format in the form `j/n/Y` it will show date as `30/7/2014`.

[image]

**Under webform date field setting choose the Default value timezone to "Website timezone"**

[image]

**P.S** If you want to reorder select boxes then see: [Re-ordering the elements of a Drupal Webform Datepicker](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/04-06-2013/re-ordering-the-elements-of-a-drupal-webform-datepicker)

Comment: @welovedesign: Does this worked for you?

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: Please make sure you use the correct webform version. It was working for me when i posted this answer. I have checked and then posted answer.